# Cannot see sprite or even rect on canvas with Kinetic?

Tags: animation, canvas, sprite, requirejs, kineticjs

I'm using requirejs to load in Kinetic, and I have a simple script to create a sprite and load it on to the canvas. It loads the sprite in a default idle state that is one frame:

```
require(['libraries/kinetic'], function(Kinetic){

  console.log('Initializing....');

  var stage  = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container : 'canvas',
    width     : 578,
    height    : 200
  }),
  layer      = new Kinetic.Layer(),
  animations = {
    idleRight: [{
      x      : 343,
      y      : 2,
      width  : 26,
      height : 58
    }]
  },
  imageObj     = new Image();
  imageObj.src = '/assets/images/billy.png';

  imageObj.onload = function() {

    var billy = new Kinetic.Sprite({
      x          : 25,
      y          : 25,
      image      : imageObj,
      animation  : 'idleRight',
      animations : animations,
      frameRate  : 7
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(billy);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);

    // start sprite animation
    billy.start();

    console.log('Done.');

  }; // .onload

}); // require
```

I'm using a shim config for require so that kinetic is loaded properly:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/assets/js',
    shim: {
        'libraries/kinetic' : {
          exports : 'Kinetic'
        },
    }
});
```

No matter what I try, I can't get the sprite/image to show up! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using this image from google as a test sprite:

```
http://www.nes-snes-sprites.com/ImagesSheet/SuperDoubleDragonSheet2.gif
```

Comment: seems like when i take the code out of the require definition, and put it on a flat html page it works. not sure exactly what's breaking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the domeReady requirejs module, and loaded it as per below:

```
require(['libraries/require/domReady!',
        'libraries/kinetic'], function(document, Kinetic){... etc
```